# Cache it or not Cache it(generate it), that is the questiion

Tags: c++

I have a collection of say 100 `double` values that has to be divided by a fix `int` variable MANY times:

```
unsigned int current_interval = double_value / int_value;
```

I need to know if the following simple cache would be a cheaper calculation or not(and why?):

```
std::map<double_value,current_interval> cache;
//...
unsigned int get_interval(double_value / int_value){
    if((it = cache.find(double_value)) != cache.end()
    {
     return it->second;
    }
    unsigned int current_interval = double_value / int_value;
    cache[double_value] = current_interval;
    return current_interval;
}
```

thank you

Comment: just cache the `current_interval` itself, even faster.. and you might wanna eagerly compute this, would be faster again to retrieve

Comment: On a modern Intel or AMD (and many other CPUs), the map lookup would likely be significantly slower than another division (given log-base-2(100) ~= 8 comparisons across scattered memory addresses), but it's hardware dependent and if you care you should implement both and measure in your actual program.  You haven't specified anything about your hardware, which makes for a very poor question.

Comment: *Never* use a floating point value as the key for a map. That way lies insanity, as you start to wonder why two seemingly identical numbers are not equal.

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for the hint. I didn’t know it is something hardware dependent, and I have no clues about hardware. I am currently working on an intel Xeon because the room here is cooler :) but the final application should run on any laptop(cross-platform, including Apple products). What if I use a `std::vector < pair<key,value> >` ? will this also be -pretty much- hardware dependent?

Comment: @rahman: a `vector` can out-perform a `map` for lookups if you keep it packed and pre-sorted, but doing so is itself expensive during insertions and deletions.  Honestly, you're wasting your time trying to optimise this division.  Finish your program, get it working nicely, then if it's too slow use a *profiler* tool or carefully placed logging/trace lines to actually measure which bits are *significantly* slow....

Comment: As your int value is fixed, you should store it additionally as double and do the division with the double.

Comment: @TonyD I learnt a bit from comments. But you were right. It is better not to be so meticulous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**: Doing the repeated division is probably faster than looking up the value in a map

**Details:**

I thought this was an interesting question.  At least from the perspective of execution time for a map lookup compared to floating point division.  Before addressing this though I want to reiterate two of the comments:

1) If you really only have 100 doubles that you are dividing by a fixed value and then using many times, I expect that you should be able to transform your algorithm to use this result directly.  I expect that would be more efficient than the proposed caching algorithm.

2) Don't use a `double` as a key in a map.

Now on to the main question.  To answer it I wrote two small programs.  The first simply looks up values in a map of size 100.  The second performs floating point division.  I've included the full source code in case anyone wants to replicate my results.  Also for the second program I've included some extra code simply to keep the same structure, but what matters in the second loop.

---

**map.cpp**

```
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>

std::map<int,int> testmap;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int count = atoi(argv[1]);
  int val   = atoi(argv[2]);
  int total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    testmap[i] = val + i;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      total += testmap[j];
    }
  }

  return total;
}
```

---

**double.cpp**

```
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>

std::map<int,int> testmap;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int count = atoi(argv[1]);
  double val   = atof(argv[2]);
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    testmap[i] = val + i;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
      total += val / j;
    }
  }

  return total;
}
```

---

I compiled with both O1 and O3 to make sure the compiler wasn't optimizing away the loop.  And I also tested with a few different iteration sizes to make sure the execution time scaled with the iteration count.

I ran my tests on a `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v3 @ 3.50GHz` system compiling with `g++ (GCC) 4.9.2`

For O1 my results running with 10000000 iterations are:

```
map: 7.1 seconds 
double: 3.6 seconds
```

For O3 my results are:

```
map: 5.3 seconds
double: 3.5 seconds
```

So the difference is not that large, but clearly the division implementation is faster in the small micro-benchmark I wrote here.  And also it is what is simpler to implement.  So I think it is highly unlikely that trying to memoize the results of division, and then look them up in a map, will be faster than simply calculating the values when you need them.  For the memoization to be useful the basic operation would need to be more expensive than floating point division which is heavily optimized in modern CPUs.

Comment: The thread opener is dividing by a fixed value, hence it will be much faster, as the loop above (division by changing value) cannot be optimized as much (besides loop unrolling) than a division by a fixed value. You should try to read doubles from a vector and divide by a fixed double from a loop. The compiler will optimize much more (you still might have to enable SSE/AVX optimization in the compiler options)

Comment: @ogni42 I assumed that the OP was asking about performing this operation as something mixed in occasionally along with other code. Thus I explicitly did not want the compiler to vectorize it, because I was trying to compare the amortize cost of a FP divide compared with a std::map lookup.  Even in the unoptimized code I wrote the divide is still cheaper.  But I agree that if the OP was interested in peak FP divide performance that writing vectorizable code would be a good idea.